# Functionality of overridden compareTo() method

Tags: java, comparable

```
public class Drink implements Comparable {
    public String name;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Drink one = new Drink();
        Drink two = new Drink();
        one.name = "Coffee";
        two.name = "Tea";
        TreeSet set = new TreeSet();    
        set.add(one);
        set.add(two);

        Iterator itr = set.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(itr.next()); //prints Tea
        }
    }
}
```

Usually, `compareTo()` method prints in lexicographical order, but when `compareTo()` method is overridden as in the above code then how it is comparing the two strings?

Comment: It isn't comparing the strings.

Comment: Did you mean to assign both `"Coffee"` and `"Tea"` to `one.name`? (Looks like a typo?) Did you mean `two.name = "Tea";`?

Comment: Yes its actually two.coffee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your compareTo method, all objects are equal to each other, since you always return 0, so when you try to add two Drink objects to your TreeSet, only the first one will be added, since a Set doesn't allow duplicates.

It would make more sense to have an implementation like this, that actually compares the names :

```
public class Drink implements Comparable<Drink> {

    public String name;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Drink o) {
        return name.compareTo(o.name);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Then why not print coffee first instead of tea?

Comment: @kittu It's arbitrary, since according to your method all Drink objects are equal (for the purpose of natural ordering).

Comment: @Radiodef I didn't notice this, but even without this typo (and I assume it's a typo), only one Drink instance would be in the TreeSet after the two additions, since both `one` and `two` would be consitered equal, and a Set doesn't allow duplicates.

Comment: Note that Comparable interface says that compareTo(null) should throw a NullPointerException

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev Thanks for your comment. I missed that.

Comment: @Eran If duplicates are not allowed in this case then how come it chooses to print tea instead of coffee as coffee is added to set first. I tried to print it no of times and it chooses tea all the time

Comment: @kittu I tried your code on Eclipse, Java 6, and it printed Coffee. If I switch the order of `set.add(one);` and `set.add(two);`, it prints Tea.

Comment: @Eran Okay, may be it depends on java version. I am using java 7. Any way thanks for checking it out

Comment: @kittu Actually, I was wrong (my other laptop has Java 6). I got "Coffee" output with Java 7.

Comment: Hmm I think it is still printing the values based on Java version. Anyway the underlying logic is that set is not accepting duplicates with overridden version of compareTo

Answer (score 1):

It is not comparing the string in this as the`comapareTo()` method is returning 0 (meaning objects are equal) so `set.add(two)` will be considered as duplicated and only the first value added will be printed.

Try reversing the order of addition of values to the set and you will get your answer

Answer (score 0):

The overridden compareTo method is used for customize comparison. In this function, you compare two objects based on your business logic and on the basis of your logic, you return -1,0 or 1, where -1 represents invoking object is smaller than the invoked object while _1 represents the other way. 0 represents that both the objects are equal.

In your code, right now it is not putting any logic. Its just returning a prototype value. You might put something like that in your code

return name.compareTo((String)o);

which will be the default functionality if you don't put your custom override method.